# posting through postman works but with python requests I get error 413

Tags: python-requests, postman, castor

When I use postman like this:
[image]

it works correctly and sets the value in database, but when I use requests library like code bellow I get error code 413:
[image]

any ideas appreciated.

Comment: what's your payload content?

Comment: that's the value of a field that I want to get updated. its current value is one, I want it to change to 2.

Comment: Postman as 10 headers - your code has 1. Add some of relevant headers? (e.g. tell it the  content type you're sending)